# Linq-Xml [DirectoryNotFound or NullReferenceException]

Tags: xml, exception, error-handling, xna, load

I'm pretty new to Xna and I want to load and read a XML file.
After searching in the internet for hours I still don't get it doesn't load the file.
Whenever I try to start it there is a (DirectoryNotFoundException) and when I try to copy it into the debug directory there is a (NullReferenceException)

DOWNLOAD: http://www.mediafire.com/?z6w36b73cufy3co

The Method for Loading: (theres a second one in the code, but I will upload the whole project anyway)

```
    private void InitLevel(int levelNum)
    {
        actlevel = levelNum;
        levelData = (from level in XElement.Load("Data\\Levels.xml").Descendants("Level")
                      where (int)level.Attribute("Number") == levelNum
                      select new LevelData
                      {
                          number = levelNum,
                          changeDirChance = (int)level.Attribute("ChangeDirChance"),
                          maxActiveAliens = (int)level.Attribute("MaxActiveAliens"),
                          totalAliensToFinish = (int)level.Attribute("TotalAliensToFinish"),
                          boss = alienTypes[(string)level.Attribute("Boss")],
                          fireChance = (int)level.Attribute("FireChance"),
                          maxAlienBullets = (int)level.Attribute("MaxAlienBullets"),
                          alienGenerationTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((int)level.Attribute("AlienGenerationTime")),
                          selectionData = (from sel in level.Descendants("AlienType")
                                           select new AlienSelectionData
                                           {
                                               chance = (int)sel.Attribute("Chance"),
                                               alien = alienTypes[(string)sel.Attribute("Name")]
                                           }).ToList()
                      }).SingleOrDefault();
        Debug.Assert(levelData != null);
    }
```

and the XML File (Levels.xml in /Data):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Levels>
  <Level Number="1" MaxActiveAliens="7" TotalAliensToFinish="15" Boss="boss1"
         AlienGenerationTime="800" ChangeDirChance="2" FireChance="2" MaxAlienBullets="5">
    <AlienTypes>
      <AlienType Name="alien1" Chance="25" />
      <AlienType Name="alien2" Chance="20" />
      <AlienType Name="alien3" Chance="20" />
      <AlienType Name="alien4" Chance="5" />
    </AlienTypes>
  </Level>
  <Level Number="2" MaxActiveAliens="10" TotalAliensToFinish="25" Boss="boss2"
         AlienGenerationTime="600" ChangeDirChance="2" FireChance="3" MaxAlienBullets="7">
    <AlienTypes>
      <AlienType Name="alien1" Chance="20" />
      <AlienType Name="alien2" Chance="20" />
      <AlienType Name="alien3" Chance="20" />
      <AlienType Name="alien4" Chance="15" />
      <AlienType Name="alien5" Chance="10" />
    </AlienTypes>
  </Level>
</Levels>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives to achieve it:

A) Using the content pipeline

This is the choice if you want to load it from an Xbox game.
   Making an importer and a processor that loads and returns it as:

1. A string.
2. Or your level type

B) Using the System.IO

Adding the file to the solution and going to the properties of the file and setting the option "Copy to output folder" to "Copy always" you will able to load the file from a folder relative to the executable. It seems that is what you need for your code but it does not work in a xbox game.

### EDIT

I have debugged your code...

1) You have to set the "copy always option" to both files "alientypes.xml" and "levels.xml"

2) You call "InitLevel" before you load "alienTypes" field, so this field is null... so InitLevelsgive a null reference exception....

```
  public void Initialize( ContentManager Content )
    {
        player.Initialize( );
        stars.Initialize( width, height );
        shot.Initialize( );
--->    InitLevel( 1 );

        // XML Datei
--->    alienTypes = (from at in XElement.Load( "data/alientypes.xml" ).Descendants( "AlienType" )
                      select new AlienType.....
```

3) I have modified your code to debug it easier... now is easy to trace it an find where is the fail... that "alientypes" is null..

```
    private void InitLevel( int levelNum )
    {
        actlevel = levelNum;
        var levels =  XElement.Load( "Data\\Levels.xml" ).Descendants( "Level" );
        var level = levels.Where( l => ( int ) l.Attribute( "Number" ) == levelNum ).SingleOrDefault( );

        levelData = new LevelData( );

        levelData.number = levelNum;
        levelData.changeDirChance = ( int ) level.Attribute( "ChangeDirChance" );
        levelData.maxActiveAliens = ( int ) level.Attribute( "MaxActiveAliens" );
        levelData.totalAliensToFinish = ( int ) level.Attribute( "TotalAliensToFinish" );
 ---->  levelData.boss = alienTypes[( string ) level.Attribute( "Boss" )];
        .....
```

### EDIT 2

Your alien types xml has several errors... the bosses need the "space" attribute, and the path Texture="Texures/sprites" of alien1 should be Texture="Textures/sprites"...